# creating a shell console to take various inputs

Tags: java

I am trying to create a console-like application, where it takes to command and print some output, I have included the print command, now want to include the exit command that will exit the Scanner. How can I achieve it?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
      Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
      System.out.println("");
      String output = getCommand(myObj);
      System.out.println(output);
    }
  }

  private static String getCommand(Scanner myObj) {
    List help = new ArrayList();
    help.add("print");
    if (myObj.nextLine().equals("print")) {
      return "Hello World";
    } else if (myObj.nextLine().equals("time")) {
      return new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").toString();
    } else if (myObj.nextLine().equals("exit")) {
      // exit the console
    }
    return Arrays.asList(help).toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Create your scanner before the loop starts in main. Otherwise you're just creating many scanners, and may eventually cause memory problems if you use the program long enough (this might take lifetimes, though).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Return `null` if the user enters `exit`, and then test for that in `main` and do a `break` to exit your main loop:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
            System.out.println("");
            String output = getCommand(myObj);
            if (output == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

    private static String getCommand(Scanner myObj) {
        List help  = new ArrayList();
        help.add("print");
        if(myObj.nextLine().equals("print")){
            return "Hello World";
        }else if(myObj.nextLine().equals("time")){
            return new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").toString();
        }else if(myObj.nextLine().equals("exit")){
            return null;
        }
        return Arrays.asList(help).toString() ;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to just call:

```
System.exit(0); (instead of doing `return null;`)
```

as soon as your test for `exit` succeeds.